# unable to display form from one class to main dashboard

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

[image]

[image]

hello guys hope so all are doing well I am new to java swing and and trying build very simple app and I am stocked in problem that I was trying to open jpanal that contain a form in main dashboard I am attaching some pics of gui please see and let me know is there any way to add that form to main dashboard
my program structure is:
one dashboard class that contain button of add and a jpanal that can hold that form
one form class that contain form
I am trying to display this form into main dashboard jpanal

```
package school_management_system;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class dashboard extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    
    JLabel header_label=new JLabel();
    JPanel panel_header=new JPanel();
    JPanel panel_left=new JPanel();
    JPanel panel_center=new JPanel();
    JPanel panel_left_sub1=new JPanel();
    JPanel panel_left_sub2=new JPanel();
    JPanel panel_left_sub3=new JPanel();
    JButton add_item_bt=new JButton();
    JButton update_item_bt=new JButton();
    JButton add_customer_bt=new JButton();
    
    dashboard()
    {
        setlocandsize();
        designcomponents();
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.setSize(620, 620);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(panel_header, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(panel_left, BorderLayout.WEST);
        this.add(panel_center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add_item_bt.addActionListener(this);
        panel_header.add(header_label);
        panel_left.add(panel_left_sub1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel_left.add(panel_left_sub2, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel_left.add(panel_left_sub3, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel_left_sub1.add(add_item_bt);
        panel_left_sub2.add(update_item_bt);
        panel_left_sub3.add(add_customer_bt);
        
    }
    public void setlocandsize()
    {
        panel_header.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
        panel_left.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,150));
        panel_center.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
        panel_left_sub1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130,50));
        panel_left_sub2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130,50));
        panel_left_sub3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130,50));
        add_item_bt.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120,30));
        update_item_bt.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120,30));
        add_customer_bt.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120,30));
        
        panel_left.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,10,20));
        panel_left_sub1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,10,10));
        panel_left_sub2.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,10,10));
        panel_left_sub3.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,10,10));
        panel_header.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,10,20));
        
    }
    public void designcomponents()
    {
        panel_header.setBackground(Color.red);
        panel_left.setBackground(Color.blue);
        panel_center.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        panel_left_sub1.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        panel_left_sub2.setBackground(Color.green);
        panel_left_sub3.setBackground(Color.orange);
        
        add_item_bt.setText("Add Item");
        update_item_bt.setText("Update item");
        add_customer_bt.setText("Add Customer");
        header_label.setText("Staff Dashboard");
        header_label.setFont(new Font("MV Boli",Font.BOLD,20));
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        if(e.getSource()==add_item_bt)
        {
            new add_item();
        }
    }
}
```

'
'

```
package school_management_system;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class add_item extends JFrame {
    JPanel add_item_panel=new JPanel();
    JLabel item_panel_label=new JLabel();
    JLabel item_name_label=new JLabel();
    JTextField item_name_tf=new JTextField();
    JLabel item_price_label=new JLabel();
    JTextField item_price_tf=new JTextField();
    JButton add_item_bt=new JButton();
    JDialog add_item_dialog=new JDialog();

    add_item()
    {
        JDialog d1;
        d1=new JDialog();
        setlocandsize();
        designcomponents();
        d1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        d1.add(add_item_panel);
        d1.setVisible(true);
        d1.setSize(500, 500);
        add_item_panel.add(item_panel_label);
        add_item_panel.add(item_name_label);
        add_item_panel.add(item_name_tf);
        add_item_panel.add(item_price_label);
        add_item_panel.add(item_price_tf);
        add_item_panel.add(add_item_bt);
        
    }
    public void setlocandsize()
    {
        add_item_panel.setBounds(100, 50, 400, 400);
        add_item_panel.setLayout(null);
        add_item_panel.setBackground(Color.gray);
        item_panel_label.setBounds(130, 0, 200, 100);
        item_name_label.setBounds(90, 60, 100, 100);
        item_name_tf.setBounds(210, 95, 100, 25);
        item_price_label.setBounds(90, 100, 100, 100);
        item_price_tf.setBounds(210, 135, 100, 25);
        add_item_bt.setBounds(230, 175, 80, 25);
        
    }
    public void designcomponents()
    {
        item_panel_label.setText("Add Item");
        item_panel_label.setFont(new Font("MV Boli",Font.BOLD,30));
        item_name_label.setText("Item Name:");
        item_name_label.setFont(new Font("MV Boli",Font.BOLD,15));
        item_price_label.setText("Item Name:");
        item_price_label.setFont(new Font("MV Boli",Font.BOLD,15));
        add_item_bt.setText("Add");
    }
}
```

'

Comment: 1. Please follow [Java Naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html)  2. You can't add 3 components to `BorderLayout.NORTH` 3. Avoid null layouts. Use layout managers all over. 4. For the secondary window use a `JDialog`

Comment: okay boss thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

First, let's fix some issues with the GUI. Read the comment to follow the changes :

```
//rename to follow naming conventions
public class Dashboard extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    //rename to follow naming conventions
    JLabel headerLabel=new JLabel();
    JPanel panelHeader=new JPanel();
    JPanel panelLeft=new JPanel();
    JPanel panelCenter=new JPanel();
    JPanel panelLeftSub1=new JPanel();
    JPanel panelLeftSub2=new JPanel();
    JPanel panelLeftSub3=new JPanel();
    JButton addItemBtn=new JButton();
    JButton updateItemBtn=new JButton();
    JButton addCustomerBtn=new JButton();

    Dashboard()
    {

        setlocandsize();
        designcomponents();
        //this.setSize(620, 620); let pack() size the window to its children
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(panelHeader, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(panelLeft, BorderLayout.WEST);
        this.add(panelCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        addItemBtn.addActionListener(this);
        panelHeader.add(headerLabel);
      //JPanel uses FlowLayout as default so BorderLayout.NORTH has no effect;
        panelLeft.add(panelLeftSub1);
        panelLeft.add(panelLeftSub2);
        panelLeft.add(panelLeftSub3);
        panelLeftSub1.add(addItemBtn);
        panelLeftSub2.add(updateItemBtn);
        panelLeftSub3.add(addCustomerBtn);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);//always at the end
    }
    public void setlocandsize()
    {
        //todo override getPreferredSize instead of setting  proffered size
        panelHeader.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
        panelLeft.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,250));
        panelCenter.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
        panelLeftSub1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130,50));
        panelLeftSub2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130,50));
        panelLeftSub3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130,50));
        //typically there is no need to set size of buttons
        //addItemBtn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120,30));
        //updateItemBtn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120,30));
        //addCustomerBtn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120,30));

        panelLeft.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,10,20));
        panelLeftSub1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,10,10));
        panelLeftSub2.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,10,10));
        panelLeftSub3.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,10,10));
        panelHeader.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,10,20));

    }
    public void designcomponents()
    {
        panelHeader.setBackground(Color.red);
        panelLeft.setBackground(Color.blue);
        panelCenter.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        panelLeftSub1.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        panelLeftSub2.setBackground(Color.green);
        panelLeftSub3.setBackground(Color.orange);

        addItemBtn.setText("Add Item");
        updateItemBtn.setText("Update item");
        addCustomerBtn.setText("Add Customer");
        headerLabel.setText("Staff Dashboard");
        headerLabel.setFont(new Font("MV Boli",Font.BOLD,20));
    }
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource()==addItemBtn)
        {
            new AddItem();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Dashboard();
    }
}

//rename to follow naming conventions and use JDialog 
class AddItem extends JDialog { 
    JPanel addItemPanel=new JPanel();
    JLabel itemPanelLabel=new JLabel();
    JTextField itemNameTf=new JTextField(15);//set size of TF by setting columns 
    JTextField itemPriceTf=new JTextField(15);
    JButton additemBtn=new JButton();

    AddItem()
    {
        designcomponents();
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(addItemPanel);
        addItemPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(addItemPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        addItemPanel.add(itemPanelLabel);

        addItemPanel.add(makeEntryPanel("Item Name:", itemNameTf));
        addItemPanel.add(makeEntryPanel("Item Price:", itemPriceTf));

        addItemPanel.add(additemBtn);
        addItemPanel.setBackground(Color.gray);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void designcomponents()
    {
        itemPanelLabel.setText("Add Item");
        itemPanelLabel.setFont(new Font("MV Boli",Font.BOLD,30));
        additemBtn.setText("Add");
    }

    private JPanel makeEntryPanel(String text, JTextField tf ){
        JPanel entry = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
        label.setFont(new Font("MV Boli",Font.BOLD,15));
        entry.add(label);
        entry.add(tf);
        return entry;
    }
}
```

Next introduce an `Item` object:

```
class Item {
    private String name;
    private double price;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

Now modify `Dashboard` and `AddItem` to use and **share** an `Item`:
Modify `Dashboard` to construct an `Item` object, and open `AddItem` dialog that configures that object:

```
public class Dashboard extends JFrame {

    JLabel headerLabel=new JLabel();
    JPanel panelHeader=new JPanel();
    JPanel panelLeft=new JPanel();
    JPanel panelCenter=new JPanel();
    JPanel panelLeftSub1=new JPanel();
    JPanel panelLeftSub2=new JPanel();
    JPanel panelLeftSub3=new JPanel();
    JButton addItemBtn=new JButton();
    JButton updateItemBtn=new JButton();
    JButton addCustomerBtn=new JButton();

    Dashboard()
    {
        setlocandsize();
        designcomponents();
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.add(panelHeader, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        this.add(panelLeft, BorderLayout.WEST);
        this.add(panelCenter, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        addItemBtn.addActionListener(e-> addItem());
        panelHeader.add(headerLabel);
        panelLeft.add(panelLeftSub1);
        panelLeft.add(panelLeftSub2);
        panelLeft.add(panelLeftSub3);
        panelLeftSub1.add(addItemBtn);
        panelLeftSub2.add(updateItemBtn);
        panelLeftSub3.add(addCustomerBtn);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);//always at the end
    }
    public void setlocandsize()
    {
        //todo override getPreferredSize instead of setting  proffered size
        panelHeader.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
        panelLeft.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,250));
        panelCenter.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
        panelLeftSub1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130,50));
        panelLeftSub2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130,50));
        panelLeftSub3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(130,50));

        panelLeft.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,10,20));
        panelLeftSub1.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,10,10));
        panelLeftSub2.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,10,10));
        panelLeftSub3.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,10,10));
        panelHeader.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER,10,20));

    }
    public void designcomponents()
    {
        panelHeader.setBackground(Color.red);
        panelLeft.setBackground(Color.blue);
        panelCenter.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        panelLeftSub1.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        panelLeftSub2.setBackground(Color.green);
        panelLeftSub3.setBackground(Color.orange);

        addItemBtn.setText("Add Item");
        updateItemBtn.setText("Update item");
        addCustomerBtn.setText("Add Customer");
        headerLabel.setText("Staff Dashboard");
        headerLabel.setFont(new Font("MV Boli",Font.BOLD,20));
    }

    private void addItem(){
        Item item = new Item();
        new AddItem(item); //invoke AddItem that updates item 
        //after AddItem is closed, print details for testing  
        System.out.println(item.getName() + " price:" + item.getPrice());
        
        //todo display details in gui
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Dashboard();
    }
}
```

the **modal** `AddItem` configures the shared `Item` object and closes when done:

```
class AddItem extends JDialog {

    private final Item item;

    JPanel addItemPanel=new JPanel();
    JLabel itemPanelLabel=new JLabel();
    JTextField itemNameTf=new JTextField(15);//set size of TF by setting columns
    JTextField itemPriceTf=new JTextField(15);
    JButton additemBtn=new JButton();

    AddItem(Item item)
    {
        this.item = item;
        setModal(true);
        designcomponents();
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(addItemPanel);

        addItemPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(addItemPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        addItemPanel.add(itemPanelLabel);

        addItemPanel.add(makeEntryPanel("Item Name:", itemNameTf));
        addItemPanel.add(makeEntryPanel("Item Price:", itemPriceTf));

        addItemPanel.add(additemBtn);
        addItemPanel.setBackground(Color.gray);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void designcomponents()
    {
        itemPanelLabel.setText("Add Item");
        itemPanelLabel.setFont(new Font("MV Boli",Font.BOLD,30));
        additemBtn.setText("Add");
        additemBtn.addActionListener(e->updateItemDetails());
    }

    private void updateItemDetails() {
        //todo check input
        //configure item 
        item.setName(itemNameTf.getText());
        item.setPrice(Double.valueOf(itemPriceTf.getText()));
        dispose();//close dialog 
    }

    private JPanel makeEntryPanel(String text, JTextField tf ){
        JPanel entry = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel(text);
        label.setFont(new Font("MV Boli",Font.BOLD,15));
        entry.add(label);
        entry.add(tf);
        return entry;
    }
}
```